# I am trying to override contact page with custom look up.Getting error

Tags: visualforce, lookup, controller-extension, page-override

Error:while clicking custom lookup saying

> "Unknown constructor 'LookupPopupController.LookupPopupController()'"

Visualforce page :

```
<apex:page StandardController="contact" extensions="LookupMainController,LookupPopupController" >
    <script>
    var newWin=null;
    function openLookupPopup(name, id)
    {
        var url="/apex/lookupoverride?namefield=" + name + "&idfield=" + id;
        newWin=window.open(url, 'Popup','height=500,width=600,left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
        if (window.focus) 
        {
            newWin.focus();
        }

        return false;
    }

    function closeLookupPopup()
    {
       if (null!=newWin)
       {
          newWin.close();
       }  
    }
</script>
<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Contact Edit" mode="edit">
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Phone Numbers">
    <apex:inputfield value="{!contact.HomePhone}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MobilePhone}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.OtherPhone}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Fax}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Contact Information">
    <apex:inputfield value="{!contact.ownerid}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Email}"/>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputlabel value="First Name"/>
            <apex:outputpanel >
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Salutation}"/>
    &nbsp;
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
            </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.AssistantName}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.LastName}"/>

    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.AssistantPhone}"/>
    <!--<apex:inputField value="{!contact.Accountid}"/>-->


      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionitem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Account"/>
          <apex:outputPanel >
            <apex:inputHidden value="{!accountId}" id="targetId" />
            <apex:inputText size="40" value="{!accountName}" id="targetName" onFocus="this.blur()" disabled="false"/> <a href="#" onclick="openLookupPopup('{!$Component.targetName}', '{!$Component.targetId}'); return false">Lookup</a>
          </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionitem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>


    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Title}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Department}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Birthdate}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.ReportsToid}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.LeadSource}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Additional Information">
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingStreet}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.OtherStreet}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingCity}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.OtherCity}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingState}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.OtherState}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingPostalCode}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.OtherPostalCode}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingCountry}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.OtherCountry}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Description Information">
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Description}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

LookupPopupController class:

```
// Custom controller for lookup example popup page

public with sharing class LookupPopupController 
{
    public String query {get; set;}
    public List<Account> accounts {get; set;}
    public LookupPopupController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    }

    public PageReference runQuery()
    {
        List<List<Account>> searchResults=[FIND :query IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account (id, name, AccountNumber, Site)];
        accounts=searchResults[0];
        return null;
    }
}
```

LookupMainController class :

```
// Custom controller for lookup example main page

public with sharing class LookupMainController 
{
    public String accountName {get; set;}
    public Id accountId {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> contacts {get;set;}
    public Contact contact{get;set;}
    public LookupMainController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        //this.contact = (Contact )controller.getRecord();
        contact = new Contact();
    }

    public PageReference findContacts()
    {
        if (null!=accountId)
        {
           contacts=[select id,FirstName, LastName from Contact where AccountId=:accountId];
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

lookupoverride page :

```
<apex:page controller="LookupPopupController" sidebar="false" showheader="false">
<script language="javascript">
   window.onload = new function() 
   { 
      // bring popup window to front
      window.focus(); 
      var ele=document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.block.section.query}');
      if (ele)
      {
         ele.focus();
      }
   }

   function fillIn(name, id)
   {
      var winMain=window.opener;
      if (null==winMain)
      {
         winMain=window.parent.opener;
      }
      var ele=winMain.document.getElementById('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.namefield}');
      ele.value=name;
      ele=winMain.document.getElementById('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.idfield}');
      ele.value=id;
      CloseWindow();
   }

   function CloseWindow()
   {
      var winMain=window.opener;
      if (null==winMain)
      {
         winMain=window.parent.opener;
      }
      winMain.closeLookupPopup();
   }
</script>

  <apex:messages />
  <apex:form id="form" >  

     <div style="width 100%">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Lookup" id="block">

          <apex:pageBlockSection id="section">
              Enter search text and click Go<br/>
              <apex:inputText value="{!query}" id="query"/> 
              <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!runQuery}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="account">
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                  <apex:outputLink value="#" onclick="fillIn('{!account.Name}', '{!account.id}')">{!account.Name}</apex:outputLink>       
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Account Number" value="{!account.AccountNumber}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Account Site" value="{!account.Site}"/>

              </apex:pageBlockTable>    
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <button type="button" onclick="CloseWindow();">Close Window</button>
     </div>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please help me.Its urgent.I am not able to figure out why constructor error is throwing on click of LOOKUP hyperlink even while initializing the constructor

Comment: Can you post the Visualforce for the "lookupoverride" page?

Comment: Dont know how to format text here.

Comment: Any help ? I am new to salesforce.

Comment: There still looks like you have some code missing. Does your lookupOverride page specify LookupPopupController as a controller extension?

Comment: Hi Derek,
I have used LookupPopupController as controller in lookupOverride page and 
LookupPopupController as extension in NewContact vf page

Comment: Ok, now I think I know what the issue is, writing up an answer.

Comment: My problem got solved.I removed LookupPopupController as extension in NewContact vf page and i removed the constructor from LookupPopupController as controller.Thanks Derek for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments on your question, `LookupPopupController` is being used as a controller (and not a controller extension) in your `lookupOverride` page.

When a class is used as the controller, and not a controller extension, it doesn't get passed an `ApexPages.StandardController`

The error you're seeing is then straightforward. You don't have a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

It looks like you can remove `LookupPopupController` from the list of controller extensions on your main Visualforce page.

To get your popup window to behave like you expect it to, you should probably have `LookupPopupController` as a controller extension for `lookupOverride`, and set `accountId` in the constructor (which should still expect an argument of type `ApexPages.StandardControllerr`)